# Prevent function to be called twice in the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function which use I/O lines to send and recieve frames.

```
var async = require('async');
function busFrame(TX, callback){
    async.series([
        function(callback){
            sendFrame(TX, function(err){
                console.log("Frame Transmitted");
                return callback(err);
            });
        },
        function(callback){
             recieveFrame(function(err){
                 console.log("Frame Recieved");
                 return callback(err);
             });
        }
    ],
    function(err){
        return callback(err);
    });
}
```

`busframe` function take some time to excute because it uses I/O lines, when i call it rapidly, it excutes more then one time in the same time. like this:

```
busFrame([1,2,3], function(err){    
});
busFrame([4,5,6], function(err){    
});
```

The output is:

```
Frame Transmitted
Frame Transmitted
Frame Recieved
Frame Recieved
```

I want to prevent the function to be called more then once in the same time and any other call should be delayed until the first call is returned.

I know i could make my calls to the function `busFrame` using `async.series()` but if there a way to prevent the call from inside `busFrame` itself, it could reduce any possible errors.

Comment: so don't use asynchronous calls inside of the function then?

Comment: I don't understand, if you could give example it will be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by setting a boolean (for example `is_processing`) to true at "Frame Transmitted", and to false at "Frame Received".

When `is_processing` is set to true and the method is called put in a queue the parameters given, when set to false process the next item in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the singleton design pattern which would result in only one instance of the function you are calling.

I.E.

```
Public [type] getinstance() {
  if instance == null {
    instance = new [type];
  }
  return (instance)
}
```